# Color cell headers based on value which is not known in advance

Tags: excel, vba

There are similar questions but they ask something like this: if value is 100 - color red, 200 - color green.

My situation - *The cell's value is unknown in advance, so there is no pattern to match or compare against*.

**My goal:**

I want to color the first cell in each column based on the first 7 characters.

For example, these are sample cells:

```
2017.09--T-2018_08_30   2017.10--T-2018_08_30   2017.09--T-2018_08_30   2017.10--T-2018_08_30   2017.08--T-2018_08_30
```

The first 7 chars are *yyyy.mm*. 1st and 3rd columns (both have 2017.09) should be of one color, 2nd and 4th (both have 2017.10) should be of different color, and the last column (2017.08) should be of different color as well.

I would like the colors to be pulled from an array of colors:

```
Dim colors() as String: colors = Array("RGB(255,99,71)", "RGB(255,127,80)", "RGB(205,92,92)", "RGB(240,128,128)", "RGB(233,150,122)", "RGB(250,128,114)", "RGB(255,160,122)", "RGB(255,69,0)", "RGB(255,140,0)", "RGB(255,165,0)")
```

**So I can visualize my goal** - I have done the same thing in JavaScript.

```js
const colors = [
 '#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6', 
 '#E6B333', '#3366E6', '#999966', '#99FF99', '#B34D4D',
 '#80B300', '#809900', '#E6B3B3', '#6680B3', '#66991A', 
   '#FF99E6', '#CCFF1A', '#FF1A66', '#E6331A', '#33FFCC',
   '#66994D', '#B366CC', '#4D8000', '#B33300', '#CC80CC', 
  '#66664D', '#991AFF', '#E666FF', '#4DB3FF', '#1AB399',
   '#E666B3', '#33991A', '#CC9999', '#B3B31A', '#00E680', 
   '#4D8066', '#809980', '#E6FF80', '#1AFF33', '#999933',
   '#FF3380', '#CCCC00', '#66E64D', '#4D80CC', '#9900B3', 
   '#E64D66', '#4DB380', '#FF4D4D', '#99E6E6', '#6666FF'
];
const used = {};

function getColor(key) {
   used[key] = used[key] || colors.shift();
   return used[key];
}

function setHeaderColor() {
 const mainTable = document.getElementById('main-table');
 const headerRow = document.querySelectorAll('#main-table tr:first-child th');
 const test = [];                // Holds first 7 chars and background color of each column header

 // Extract first 7 characters from column header name
 for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
  test.push({
   version: headerRow[i].innerHTML.substring(0, 7),
   color: headerRow[i].style.backgroundColor || null
  });
 }

 for (let i = 1; i < test.length; i++) {
   test[i].color = getColor(test[i].version);
 }

 for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
  headerRow[i].style.backgroundColor = test[i].color;
 }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setHeaderColor);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<table class="w3-table-all" id="main-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="w3-center"> Name</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.10-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709.</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.09-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709.</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.10-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.09-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.08-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub color_header()
    Dim colors(): colors = Array(RGB(255, 99, 71), RGB(255, 127, 80), RGB(205, 92, 92), RGB(240, 128, 128), RGB(233, 150, 122), RGB(250, 128, 114), RGB(255, 160, 122), RGB(255, 69, 0), RGB(255, 140, 0), RGB(255, 165, 0))
    Dim a As Integer: a = 0
    Dim D1 As Object: Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Range("A1:E1") 'This is your header area
    Dim R0 As Range

    For Each R0 In R1
        If Not D1.exists(Left(R0, 7)) Then
            D1.Add Left(R0, 7), a
            R0.Interior.Color = colors(a)
            a = a + 1
        Else
            R0.Interior.Color = colors(D1(Left(R0, 7)))
        End If
    Next R0
End Sub
```

[image]

A few way to narrow dynamic ranges:

If you know first data is in `A1`, change `Range("A1:E1")` to :

`Range("A1",cells(1,Columns.Count).end(XlToLeft))`

If you only know that the data is on row 1 you can try :

`Intersect(Rows(1),Activesheet.Usedrange)`

Note that this is all assuming you are working on the activesheet. Consider adding workbook and worksheet referencing to avoid errors.

Multiple sheets version:

```
Sub color_header()
    Dim colors(): colors = Array(RGB(255, 99, 71), RGB(255, 127, 80), RGB(205, 92, 92), RGB(240, 128, 128), RGB(233, 150, 122), RGB(250, 128, 114), RGB(255, 160, 122), RGB(255, 69, 0), RGB(255, 140, 0), RGB(255, 165, 0))
    Dim a As Integer: a = 0
    Dim D1 As Object: Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R0 As Range

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Set R1 = Ws.Range("A1", Ws.Cells(1, Ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        For Each R0 In R1
            If Not D1.exists(Left(R0, 7)) Then
                D1.Add Left(R0, 7), a
                R0.Interior.Color = colors(a)
                a = a + 1
            Else
                R0.Interior.Color = colors(D1(Left(R0, 7)))
            End If
        Next R0
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it tomorrow and will surely update whether it worked well or not.

Comment: I just checked, and it works. Thanks a lot! However, is there a way for me to get `R1` dynamically? For example, now it is set to `"A1:E1"`. What if I do not know in advance which columns have data?

Comment: I used `Intersect` solution and it worked, but the issue is that I need to start from column B - B1. Intersect start from first column - A. I like your first edited solution with `Range` but I get the error: `Object doesn't support this property/method`. I also try to apply this somehow to all my sheets in the workbook. Whenever I call this function, I call it inside `For Each ws In MyBook.Worksheets ... Next ws` but it does not get applied to all sheets. Any help? Thanks

Comment: `Intersect` does not necessarily start at column A but I agree it is sometimes tricky to get the right behavior with it. I fixed the first option, just a typo. I'll edit for multiple sheets.

Comment: Change A1 to B1 as it seems to be your starting point and note that the color coding stays consistent within the sheets so be careful if you have more different codes than your stored colors.

Comment: Thank you a lot - works exactly as I needed! What do you mean by "different codes"?

Comment: I mean different dates in your data. You have a limited number of color stored in your array so you'll run into a problem if you try to color a lot of different dates.